# Pop a UIViewController containing a UITabBarController off of a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UINavigationController(a) that pushes a UIViewController(b) onto the stack. (b) contains a UITabBarController(c). (c) has 5 tabs and any of these ViewControllers(d,e,f,g,h) needs to be able to pop (b) off the stack.

I've tried [[self.parentViewController navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; among many other things, none of which seem to work. Any ideas?

Edit:

.h file:

```
@interface MATabViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
UIViewController *ref;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgViewFooter;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "MATabViewController.h"

@implementation MATabViewController
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;
@synthesize imgViewFooter;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.view = self.tabBarController.view;

self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.imgViewFooter.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 395.0f, 320.0f, 64.0f);
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:self.imgViewFooter];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

ref = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
}

-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

NSInteger index = [[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];

switch (index) {
    case 0:
        self.imgViewFooter.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer_full.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        self.imgViewFooter.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer_full.png"];
        break;
    case 2:
        self.imgViewFooter.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer_full.png"];
        break;
    case 3:
        self.imgViewFooter.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer_full.png"];
        break;
    case 4:
        self.imgViewFooter.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer_full.png"];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
return YES;
}

-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
if (ref != viewController) {
    [ref viewDidDisappear:YES];
    ref = viewController;
    [viewController viewDidAppear:YES];
}
}

@end
```

notice how I have a major hack in this line:

```
self.view = self.tabBarController.view;
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to pop back to (a) from (d-h)?  If so, `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` should do the trick since all of the views should inherit the same navigation controller as they are in the root's stack

Comment: yea, that does not work, unfortunatly... I just tried it. I think (b) needs to call it but I can't seem to get it to...

Comment: This is just a guess, but `[[[[self.tabBarController parentViewController] navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` might be a more direct route.  It pretty much tells the (d-h) view controllers to call their parent tabBarController, which then calls its parent, then the nav controller

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work... :(

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not good app design. Who calls popViewController? I'm guessing there's a back button in each view controller's view of your tab bar, right? Suppose the user has been switching tabs -- he might think that the back button is going to lead him into the previously selected tab, don't you agree? Even if you find a way to get this to work, I suggest you find an alternative way to organize your interface.

Comment: @miamk There may be situations in which this design has sense, though. Think about a home view and a control panel (with multiple settings). You can use a navigation controller to navigate from home to control panel and back, while the tab bar can let you navigate among the control panel's views. This case it's pretty obvious that the back button in the navigation bar won't show the last view selected but will bring you to the home view. I won't say it's not a good design, I'd rather say that it depends :)

Comment: @miamk thanks for the answer, but without seeing the actual app, how can you make the assumption that it is a bad app design?

Comment: Because a Tab Bar Controller is a higher hierarchy controller than a Navigation Controller. That's what the user expects (and Apple as well, check out the HIG). You are essentially inverting the expected hierarchy. But you are right, I have not seen your app. And picking up what @Saphrosit said, if you have a good sense about it, it might actually work. Although I have my doubts the way you described it. I'm just giving you a heads up. Cheers.

Comment: @Lance, still on that Nav/Tabbar controller debate, I suggest you check this answer to a question posted today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859868/popping-viewcontroller-doesnt-call-viewwillappear-when-going-back/6859964#6859964

Comment: Actually, I think it might even explain your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem (if I get the question). May you declare your `UIViewController` (b) as a subclass of `UITabBarController`? Notice that `UITabBarController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so you can keep using it as a normal `UIViewController`. This way you'll have (b) and (c) in a single controller. 
Now `[self.navigationController popViewController];` should work. 
At least, that's the way I solved it.

Comment: This seems like the best solution, could you go into more detail on how to accomplish this? I'll update my question with code from UIViewController(b)

Comment: in .h simply declare your MATabViewController as a subclass of UITabBarController (the protocol is ok, no need to change it), and remove the @property statement of *tabBarController. In .m remove remove the @synthesize statement and, in viewDidLoad, replace `self.tabBarController` with simply `self` (that's because self IS a tabBarController). Didn't try it, but it should work.

Comment: Seems like `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];` is the way to do it now (iOS 5.1). Or     `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true];` depending on how far you want to go.