# Popping ViewController doesn't call viewWillAppear when going back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Whenever I pop a view controller manually, `viewWillAppear` doesn't get called on the previous `UIViewController` that now appears.

These are 2 regular `UIViewControllers`. My application setup is like this:

```
- UINavigationController
   - UITabViewController with 5 UIViewControllers including UIViewControllerA
      -UIViewControllerA (When I get back here, viewWillAppear doesnt get called)
        -UIViewControllerB (I'm here, I want to pop to A)
```

I've tried calling `viewWillAppear` manually, but that doesn't help either. What could be wrong? My last resort will be popping B, and A, and then creating a new A, and pushing that, but that's only as a last resort(I assume this will work?)

Comment: if it's a modal then viewwillappear won't be called. That's how the architecture is. You need to create a delegate in Modal and implement it in the parent ViewController. So when something happens in the model viewcontroller you can tracethem back in parent ViewController.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a `UITabBarController` "inside" of a `UINavigationController`. That's probably why some of the `viewWillAppear` methods aren't being called.  Take a look here:
[Tab bar controller inside a navigation controller, or sharing a navigation root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v)

Answer (score 1):

I have created this class that solves your problem. I have used it in many of my own projects.

Just set it as a delegate of your navigation controller, and implement simple one or two methods in your view controller - that will get called when the view is about to be shown or has been shown via NavigationController

[Here's the GIST showing the code](https://gist.github.com/greggjaskiewicz/70f4a37cf6abc51423c9ecbb0033d6c7)