# viewWillAppear method not being called after popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, viewwillappear, poptoviewcontroller

I have a view controller,that is a `UINavigationController`, that at some point pushes (`navigationcontroller pushViewController: animated:`) a second view that later pushes a third view where I have a button that pops back to the root view (`popToRootViewController: animated:`). The problem is that  after the view is poped back to the root one, the method `viewWillApper` of the root view is not being called. I've set some breakpoints to check it and it's just not passing through it. I have a method to reload some contents of my root view placed in the `viewWillApper` and its being completely passed  by after the `popToRootViewController: animated`.
Any idea of what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Are you nesting various types of view controllers together?  Apparently that's not supported...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859868/popping-viewcontroller-doesnt-call-viewwillappear-when-going-back

Answer (score 0):

I used a delegate method to force the update of my view after popToRootViewController.  My rootViewController called a network upload class and, on completion, I wanted to reset the form fields on the rootViewController.

In the network upload class, I created a delegate protocol:

```
@protocol MyNetworkDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) uploadCompleted;
@end

@interface MyNetworkUploader : NSObject{
    id <MyNetworkDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) id delegate;

//other properties here

+(id)sharedManager;
-(int)writeAssessments;

@end
```

In MyNetworkUploader.m:

```
-(int)writeAssessments{
   //code here to do the actual upload
   //.....

   //this is a non-view class so I use a global navigation controller
   //maybe not the best form but it works for me and I get the required
   //behaviour
   [globalNav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
   [[globalNav.view viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
   [_delegate uploadCompleted];
}
```

Then, in my rootViewController:

```
//my upload is done within a completion block so I know when
//it's finished
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);

-(void) uploadAssessment:(myCompletion) compblock{
    //do the upload
    sharedManager=[MyNetwork sharedManager]; //create my instance
    sharedManager.delegate=self;  //set my rootViewController as the network class delegate
    int numWritten= [sharedManager writeAssessments]; 
    compblock(YES);
}

#pragma mark - protocol delegate
-(void)uploadCompleted{
    //this is a local method that clears the form
    [self clearTapped:nil];
}
```

I'm NOT proposing that this is the best solution but it worked a treat for me!

Answer (score 0):

When using a navController to push, assuming VC1 is pushing VC2 and you are using a custom presentation style to push your VC2, depending on which style you choose viewWillAppear of VC1 will not be called when VC2 is popped. Here is a list of when  is called according to its presentation style.

**UIModalPresentationStyle, iPhone, iPad**

.fullScreen                  YES     YES
.pageSheet                   YES     NO
.formSheet                   YES     NO
.currentContext              YES     YES
.custom                      NO      NO
.overFullScreen              NO      NO
.overCurrentContext          NO      NO
.blurOverFullScreen          only on tvOS - N/A, N/A
.popover                     YES     NO
.none                       CRASH    CRASH

[reference found here](https://medium.com/livefront/why-isnt-viewwillappear-getting-called-d02417b00396)